# If Date & Time changes with certain criteria & time

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I am really scratching my head over this query.

I need to update a cell with certain time stamp if possible.

Saturday, Sunday & Monday I want to have the dates fall back to Friday @ 12:00:00

However if Cell A1 lands on a Tue,Wed,Thur,Fri. I want to make the date & time -24 hours with the below criteria/exception

Another catch
If the Cell A1 has/contains a time stamp of >12:00:00 then have the date/time back tracked to the previous day @ 12:00:00

If the Cell A1 has/contains a time stamp of <12:00:00 then have the date/time back track to the previous day @ 10:00:00

Example that I am trying to achieve.

Example A which lands on a **Saturday**
If Cell A1 = 3/11/2018 @ 15:00:00 then fall back to 2/11/2018 @ 12:00:00 (Friday)

Example B which lands on a **Sunday**
If Cell A1 = 4/11/2018 @ 15:00:00 then fall back to 2/11/2018 @ 12:00:00 (Friday)

Example C which lands on a **Thursday** but after 12:00:00
If Cell A1 = 8/11/2018 @ 15:00:00 then fall back to the 7/11/2018 @ 12:00:00

Example D which lands on a **Thursday** but before 12:00:00
If Cell A1 = 8/11/2018 @ 07:30:00 then fall back to 7/11/2018 @ 10:00:00

Does this make sense? I am trying to automate Cutoff schedules for my team without too much mucking around on excel.

Regards
JW

Answer (score 1):

Non VBA option :

`=IF(WEEKDAY(A2,16)<4,INT(A2-WEEKDAY(A2,16))+0.5,IF((A2-INT(A2))>0.5,INT(A2)-0.5,INT(A2)-1+TIMEVALUE("10:00:00")))`
[image]

Comment: Hi @O.PAL, Your response helps me the best, however I have one glitch.. See below screendump

Comment: How do I add the screendump?

Comment: Turns out I cannot add the screendump.  Issue I have is that I currently have a date of 24/11/2018 08:00:00 (Saturday) but its only rolling back to the 23/11/2018 @ 12:00 where as I believe it should be 10:00:00

Comment: Hi, you specifically stated :`Saturday, Sunday & Monday I want to have the dates fall back to Friday @ 12:00:00` so I used this as a rule.

Comment: Thanks O.PAL, I am deeply grateful for your assistance. How hard it is to add the additional criteria of if Saturday before 12:00 then roll back to Friday @ 10:00am

Comment: @JDogg This should do:`=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,17)<3,INT(A1-WEEKDAY(A1,16))+0.5,IF((A1-INT(A1))>0.5,INT(A1)-0.5,INT(A1)-1+TIMEVALUE("10:00:00")))` placed in `B1` for a date in `A1`

Answer (score 0):

I think this matches the logic you described, but it doesn't come anywhere close to the results you were expecting to see.  Maybe use it as a boilerplate and see where my understanding or your examples (or both) might be off:

```
Function FunWithDates(InputDate As Double) As Date

  Dim dow As Integer
  Dim dateOnly As Long
  Dim timeOnly As Double

  dateOnly = int (InputDate)
  remainder = InputDate - dateOnly
  dow = Weekday(InputDate)

  If dow = 7 Then  ' Saturday
    FunWithDates = dateOnly - 0.5
  ElseIf dow = 1 Then ' Sunday
    FunWithDates = dateOnly - 1.5
  ElseIf dow = 2 Then ' Monday
    FunWithDates = dateOnly - 2.5
  ElseIf remainder > 0.5 Then
    FunWithDates = dateOnly - 0.5
  ElseIf remainder < 0.5 Then
    FunWithDates = dateOnly - 1 + (10 / 24)
  End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: One of the problems with your coding is that when you convert a `Double` to a `Long` data type, the value is rounded, not truncated.  You don't take this into account. Hence, your errors when the time >= 12:00

Comment: @RonRosenfeld -- I had no idea.  Thanks for the correction; VBA is pretty far down my list of tools, so I clearly don't know it as well as I should